# .net compact framework 2.0 and windows embedded standard

Tags: compact-framework

Will the applications written in .net CF 2.0 run on windows embedded standard OS?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  CF assemblies are retargetable, so the full framework (which is what comes on Embedded Standard) can theoretically run them.  That said, if the assembly uses *any* CE-specific stuff (like P/Invoking coreddl.dll) then it's going to fail when it tries those operations.

Comment: thanks Chris. No p/invoke used. Actually the application doesn't contain any native calls. So provided that, the device will run the app?

Comment: As ctacke stated, if your application was designed for CF, and it does not use pinvoke, then it will run on the full framework as well.

Comment: @yms, that was not the question. The question was whether it will run on Windows Embedded OS. Or are you implying that windows embedded OS has full framework and not compact one?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea, take a closer look to ctacke's answer: "so the full framework (which is what comes on Embedded Standard)..."

Comment: thanks yms! I must have read the second half of the answer only.

Comment: WES *is* just Windows 7 in a componentized form.  If it has the .NET framework included, then it will behave just like a standard desktop Win7 machine, so testing is pretty easy, even without the target.